# issue with getting started with kivy (kv language) in visual Code, empty window and no widgets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

Ive already came across with some other questions similar to this one and none could help at all. I just installed Kivy through pip install (only use a single venv) and I made two simple example-boxes via python and they did worked in VScode. Then an issue starts as I try to use kv language. It turns out that nothing happens, that is, my app runs and a black window is the only thing.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app  import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Action(BoxLayout):
    def sum(self):
        self.ids.lb.text =str(int(self.ids['lb'].text)+1)

class box(App):

        def build(self):          
            return Action()

if __name__=='__main__':
    box().run()
```

The kivy seems to be properly installed because I had already ran a python code (boxLayout) once before. The main difficulty is to get Vscode to recognize the kv file, and I couldnt find it nowhere else yet. Thank u all in advance, and also I attach here the kv. code that  interacts with the py one.[image: kivy language code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are following the correct conventions.

The following [documentation](https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/kivy-tutorial/the-kv-design-language-kv-file/) explains the naming convention for your Kivy class and `*.kv` file:

> **Naming for your `*.kv` file**:
>
> 1. It must be all lowercase
> 2. It must match the name of your main class.
> 3. If the name of your main class ends in "app" (lowercase or uppercase) you must not include "app" in your file name.

The following is the `main.py` file with the correct naming convention:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Action(BoxLayout):
    def sum(self):
        self.ids.lb.text = str(int(self.ids['lb'].text) + 1)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Action()


MainApp().run()
```

The following is the `main.kv` file with the appropriate tag:

```
<Action@BoxLayout>

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Button'
        on_release: root.sum()

    Label:
        id: lb
        text: '0'
```

Here is the resulting output:

[image]

Clicking the button increases the value in the label.

Comment: Hello Pins, firstly thanks a lot. I reproduced every step You recommended nvertheless it keeps not working. I just realized it must have smth to do with my VScode, because even  copyied codes from internet doesn't work (through .kv file). Once I have this due project, Ill try to search more. Id appreciate a lot If guys could indicate a solution for setting VScode in a better way, (like extentions, versioning, etc). That's it, Ty all

Comment: Well, problem fixed, the crap was to have the main class file name as "main.py" and it's not allowed by VScode (and it doesn't let u know either)  Cya